# How to animate WPF data bound Line item (Shape)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using MVVM, binding to an `ObservableCollection<Shape>` (DrawingInstructions) and would like to animate `Line` shapes being added.

The individual lines shall be drawn fra (X1,Y1) to (X2,Y2) in a `DoubleAnimation` kind of way.

I've tried with variations over the following, which does not work.

```cs
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DrawingInstructions}">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate >
        <Canvas>
            :
        </Canvas>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard >
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentLine" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Position" From="{Binding Path=X1}" To="{Binding Path=X2}"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentLine" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Position" From="{Binding Path=Y1}" To="{Binding Path=Y2}"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>                  
    </EventTrigger>
</ItemsControl.Triggers>
```

The Viewmodel contains code that names the Line's being added to the drawing instructions.

```
var line = new Line
{
    X1 = currentSituation.Position.X,
    Y1 = currentSituation.Position.Y,
    X2 = newSituation.Position.X,
    Y2 = newSituation.Position.Y,
    Name = "CurrentLine",
    Stroke = brush,
    StrokeThickness = 2
};
drawingInstructions.Add(line);
```

**UPDATE:**

The solution suggested by @Nico works -- introduce a "model" class representing a `Line` with `X1`, `X2`, `Y1`, `Y2` and `TimeOffset` properties. Data bind to `ObservableCollection<MyModelClass>` using the individual properties in the animation:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Line Name="CurrentLine" X1="{Binding X1}" Y1="{Binding Y1}" X2="{Binding X1}" Y2="{Binding Y1}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2">
            <Line.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentLine" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X2" BeginTime="{Binding Path=TimeOffset}" From="{Binding Path=X1}" To="{Binding Path=X2}"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentLine" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y2" BeginTime="{Binding Path=TimeOffset}" From="{Binding Path=Y1}" To="{Binding Path=Y2}"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Line.Triggers>
        </Line>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: What exactly is `currentLine`? Is this the `System.Windows.Shapes.Line`? You cannot animate a `Position` property on this object, because there is no property with this name. Please add the definition of your Shape class.

Comment: @Nico Sorry, you're right .. `CurrentLine` is the name of the `Line` added to the `ObservableCollection` (in the ViewModel code). I'll modify the question to reflect this. I'm using this approach as a (possible?) alternative to a `ValueConverter` (`Shape` --> `Line`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot bind your ItemsControl to a collection of Lines and display them as lines. Instead you should create a model class that has the necessary properties. Otherwise you will get a WPF error. I used these classes for testing:

```
public class VM
{
    public ObservableCollection<DrawingInstruction> DrawingInstructions { get; set; }
}

public class DrawingInstruction
{
    public double X1 { get; set; }
    public double X2 { get; set; }
    public double Y1 { get; set; }
    public double Y2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then, as already mentioned, you should target the X2 and Y2 property in your animation. Here is the XAML that worked for me:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DrawingInstructions}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate >
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Line Name="CurrentLine" X1="{Binding X1}" Y1="{Binding Y1}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2">
                <Line.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard >
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentLine" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X2" From="{Binding Path=X1}" To="{Binding Path=X2}"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentLine" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y2" From="{Binding Path=Y1}" To="{Binding Path=Y2}"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Line.Triggers>
            </Line>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>            
</ItemsControl>
```

The animation starts as soon the control is loaded. I hope that was your intention. Because every item has its own animation, you should add the animation to the ItemTemplate.

Comment: DataTemplate for Lines and binding Lines to DrawingInstruction DTO's is a very good idea, thanks! I'll try it out and report back (and accept the answer)

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get report back - I've now marked your solution as accepted. But, I'm having trouble triggering the animation not on load (as you suggested), but when the observable collection changes. I've tried with a variety of triggers (EventTrigger, DataTrigger), adding attached behaviours but with no luck .. I'm unable to both data bind and trigger the animation.

Comment: Have you tried the on load? Because the line is generated (and the animation is started) when an according item is being added to the collection. Or do you need the whole collection to start animation when an item is added or removed?

Comment: I'm trying to animate the line drawing, and it should only animate once. Perhaps I'm on the wrong road here, but if you're interested in the context, please look at [mhslogo.codeplex.com](http://mhslogo.codeplex.com)

Comment: That looks like the `Load` event is fine. But if you want to animate the lines one after the other, add a begin time to the `DrawingInstruction`.

Comment: Ok, I know got the animation triggered (on load), but the lines are drawn fully on load and then animated in sequence. I've modified the question to show the code (please notice the added X2 and Y2 bindings, which your answer are missing). How do I get rid of the initial line drawing?

Comment: The `X2` and `Y2` bindings have not been necessary because they were set by the animation. If the animation starts later, you have to set them to the start point. So `X2="{Binding X1}"` and `Y2={Binding Y1}`.